# preg_match_all получить данные между тэгами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста, как выбрать данные между тэгами `</a>` и `[/caption]`?

У меня есть такой код

```
[caption id="attachment_10925" align="alignnone" width="580"]<a href=""><img class="size-full wp-image-10925" title="image title" src="" alt="" width="580" height="461" /></a> Текст который нужно выбрать[/caption]
```

Comment: `preg_match_all("/<\/a>([^caption]*)\[\/caption\]/umi",
    $someBigTextForMatching,
    $out);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out[1]);
echo '</pre>';`

Comment: увы, но не работает :(

Comment: что именно не работает?     https://ideone.com/uO3y1R

Comment: ой, простите, все в порядке. спасибо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не совсем правильный шаблон: например, если в тексте, который нужно выбрать, встретиться любая из букв «caption», то поиск потерпит [неудачу](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55d90a235fa1c0cc0154ff19e7d50a8ad5c3d0ef).

Comment: @w3lifer да, возможно) наверное надо было что-то типа `<\/a>(.*?)\[\/caption\]` ..... хотя вижу в ответе подобное написано как раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$str = '[caption id="attachment_10925" align="alignnone" width="580"]<a href=""><img class="size-full wp-image-10925" title="image title" src="" alt="" width="580" height="461" /></a> Текст 
который нужно выбрать[/caption]';


echo preg_replace( '=.*?\</a\>(.*?)\[/caption\].*?=s', '$1', $str );
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81e7bc661f79e173ec6c7fd8fc2f34e25d05a5eb

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php